# Show that $G(s)=1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$ is the probability generating function of a nonnegative integer valued random variable

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I'm working on the following exercise:

> Show that $G(s)=1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$ is the probability generating function of a nonnegative integer valued random variable when $\alpha, \beta\in(0,1)$.

I tried the following:

The probability generating function of a discrete random variable $X$ is defined by $G_X(s)=\mathbb{E}(s^X)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}s^k\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=k)$, and thus $G_X^{(k)}(0)=k!\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=k)$, where $G_X^{(k)}(s)$ denotes the $k$'th derivative with respect to $s$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\frac{G_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$. Working this out I find:

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X=0)&=\frac{G_X^{(0)}(0)}{0!}=G_X^{(0)}(0)=G_X(0)=1-\alpha\\
\mathbb{P}(X=1)&=\frac{G_X^{(1)}(0)}{1!}=\alpha\beta\\
\mathbb{P}(X=2)&=\frac{G_X^{(2)}(0)}{2!}=\frac{\alpha\beta(1-\beta)}{2!}\\
& \ \ \vdots\\
\mathbb{P}(X=n)&=\frac{G_X^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{\alpha\beta(1-\beta)(2-\beta)\cdots(n-\beta)}{n!}\\
\end{align}$$

If $\alpha, \beta\in(0,1)$ it follows that all probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X=k)$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ are in $(0,1)$. For this nonnegative integer valued random variable I will assume that $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$ for $x\not\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

To show that this is indeed the probability generating function of some nonnegative integer valued random variable I have to show that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X=k)=1-\alpha+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha\beta(1-\beta)(2-\beta)\cdots(k-\beta)}{k!}\\=1-\alpha+\alpha\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\beta(1-\beta)(2-\beta)\cdots(k-\beta)}{k!}$$ equals $1$. I didn't succeed to show this, but I have the feeling I have to use the Binomial Theorem somehow. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $G(1)$ represent?

Comment: Do you mean this as a hint or as a question? Because if it is a hint: you don't show that way that this is a pgf for a discrete random variable that takes only nonnegative integer values, right? It can stil be any discrete random variable, if only $G(1)=1$, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Expanding $G(s) = 1- \alpha +\alpha\beta s + \alpha\frac{\beta(1-\beta)}{2!} s^2+\cdots$ and then (with your earlier results) letting $s=1$ should be sufficient

Comment: Yes, but I had that already in my last line, right? My question is how to show that this series equals zero indeed.

Comment: $1- \alpha +\alpha\beta s + \alpha\frac{\beta(1-\beta)}{2!} s^2+\cdots$ is a convergent series (each term is less in absolute value than the corresponding term in the expansion of $e^{|s|}$, which converges absolutely) and is equal to $1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$.  So you can safely let $s=1$ to show   $(1- \alpha) +\alpha\beta  + \alpha\frac{\beta(1-\beta)}{2!} +\cdots = 1-\alpha(1-1)^{\beta}=1-0=1 $

Comment: But what we have here is the Taylor series expansion for $1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$, right? From that it converges, can we directly conclude that it indeed converges to $1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}$?

Comment: Why calculate the Taylor series? You already have the closed form...

Comment: I have (or maybe had) the idea that we have to show that all probabilities are positive and sum up to one, for nonnegative integer values. I didn't know that the criteria you gave in your answer were sufficient to conclude it is indeed a pgf for a  nonnegative integer valued random variable.

Comment: These criteria are exactly the ones that you are trying to show. The derivatives of any order are positive, so the probabilities are positive, since $P(X=n)=\frac{G^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ (you have to show that, as you already have. Just give the formula for $G^{(n)}$). Now, the catch is that to show that they sum up to 1, you can abandon them and just use the given formula.

Comment: Okay, this makes it clear for me :) Thanks! Just for the sake of exercise then: do you think it is possible to show $1-\alpha+\alpha\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\beta(1-\beta)(2-\beta)\cdots(k-\beta)}{k!}$ equals $1$? Possibly using the binomial theorem or otherwise? So actually that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\beta(1-\beta)(2-\beta)\cdots(k-\beta)}{k!}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$, your $G$ satisfies

1. $0< G(s)<1$ for all $s\in[0,1)$.
2. $G$ is infinitely differentiable on $[0,1)$ with $G^{(n)}\ge 0$.
3. $\lim_{s\to 1^-}G(s)=\lim_{s\to 1^-}1-\alpha(1-s)^{\beta}=1$.

So $G$ is a probability generating function.

---

Edit: You are trying to use that $G(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{G^{(n)}(0)}{n!}s^n$, but you do not have to calculate the power series on the RHS and plug in $s=1$. You already have its closed form (the LHS) and you can do this directly.